# Laravel 5.8 with mpdf

Tags: mpdf

In Laravel 5.3 and 5.4, mpdf 7 was work very well.
Now:
Installed mpdf with new laravel 5.8 project.
I used the command: 
composer require mpdf/mpdf
I noticed the installation begins with:
Using version ^8.0 for mpdf/mpdf.

I thought I was installing mpdf v7.
Now i receive vendor.autoload.php not found , 
When I remove the (require autoload line) I receive the error: class mpdf/mpdf not found.

How to overcome this problem?

I've tried 
1) Install by composer, 
2) Install manually by copying (mpdf) folder into my public folder..
No luck

Comment: Are you really requiring `vendor.autoload.php`? Don't you mean `vendor/autoload.php`? Not having the autoload present most likely means you didn't let composer finish installing. There is no conflict of mpdf with laravel 5.8 and there is not much changed between mPDF 7 and 8.

Comment: Worked without require (autoload.php) file, just loaded constructor with argument, and worker very well.